# why is the terminal showing nothing in this case

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StSiZ.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> //gives us access to ifstream objects
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
//fn+f5
int main() {
    ifstream billFile; //Create a vraiavle of type ifstream to read from file

    billFile.open("bill.in"); //opening file

    string firstNum;
    billFile >> firstNum;
    cout << firstNum << endl;

    billFile.close(); // closing file
}
```

All I need is to display 12 but when I run my code the terminal is empty with no errors.

Comment: Perhaps you should check `if (!billFile.is_open()) { /* your file wasn't opened */ }` before you attempt to read from it? You should also check `if (!(billFile >> firstNum)) { /* error on read occurred */ }`. Always validate EVERY input-output operation.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Most likely because the file either does not exist, or is not in the application's working directory, which is not necessarily the same thing the directory where you keep your source. You are probably using some kind of IDE and should read its manual.

Comment: Ok the file does not open, you are correct, is there any obvious way why it's not?

Comment: How are you running the program? Where is the `bill.in` located in relation to the project? What is the programs [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)?

Comment: both files, bill.cpp and bill.in are in one folder called bill, I just added a photo of my directory

Comment: It doesn't answer how you run your program. There is a thing called "(current) working directory" (CWD), which is used as a root to resolve relative paths like "bill.in" (which is equivalent to "./bill.in"). We don't know where that CWD is. Alternatively, try an absolute path.

Comment: Use getcwd (from <unistd.h>) to find out where you are and to copy your bill.in there or chdir to where bill.in is or open with full path.

Answer (score 0):

In the (likely) case you are using Microsoft Visual Studio to compile your program, this is a (stupendously) common problem for beginners.

It is because VS puts the compiled `.exe` file in a special directory — *not* the same directory as your source code!

There are two ways to handle this from the IDE:

### #1 Modify the Project Options.

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2022), you

1. Right-click on the project node in **Solution Explorer** and select **Properties**.
2. Select the **General** tab.
3. In the configuration drop-down at the top, choose **All Configurations**.
4. Find the **Output directory** edit and change it to `$(ProjectDir)` (or to the actual full path of the source file directory, if different than where the project file is kept).

Save your changes and try again.

### #2 Add the filename as a command argument to your program

You would have to change your program code to accept a filename as argument to `main()`:

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    std::cerr << "Missing argument FILENAME\n";
    return 1;
  }

  std::ifstream f( argv[1] );
  ...
```

You will also have to tell VS to use the full path as argument to your program. Again you will need to:

1. Go to the **Solution Explorer** and select **Properties**.
2. Choose **Debug** (or **Publish**, whichever one you are using to compile).
3. Change the **Command Line Arguments** to contain the full path of the input file. Don’t forget to double-quote it if it contains spaces!

This seems more annoying, but it gives your program superpowers — like allowing you to drag and drop a file on the executable in **Windows Explorer**, or to run the program from the command line with different input files.

### #3 Compile and execute from the command line

I will not describe this one unless asked. (I’m currently tired of typing, and my sugar is dropping below 60, so I need to attend to that.)